# I'm trying to add a word filter but it doesnt seem to be working

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

I know you're not supposed to follow a youtube tutorial, but i did, and now i regret it as im here.

I would say "testautomod", or "pleasework" in my discord channel but nothing would happen.. ive been screaming at my computer for the last hour

```
package diabot;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.guild.GuildMessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Automod extends ListenerAdapter {
    
    public void onGuildMessageRecived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
        
        String[] LIST_OF_BAD_WORDS = {"testautomod", "pleasework", "gamermomentitdoesntwork" };
        String[] message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < LIST_OF_BAD_WORDS.length; b++) {
                if (message[i].equalsIgnoreCase(LIST_OF_BAD_WORDS[b])) {
                    event.getMessage().delete().queue();
                    
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you register the listener?

Comment: @dan1st yes I did

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have a typo in your method name, it should read
`onGuildMessageReceived` and not `onGuildMessageRecived`.

To avoid this, always use `@Override` when implementing JDA defined methods. If you do this and you make a typing mistake again, your IDE will notify you that there is no such method in the parenting class.

Your code should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {
    
    String[] LIST_OF_BAD_WORDS = {"testautomod", "pleasework", "gamermomentitdoesntwork" };
    String[] message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < LIST_OF_BAD_WORDS.length; b++) {
            if (message[i].equalsIgnoreCase(LIST_OF_BAD_WORDS[b])) {
                event.getMessage().delete().queue();
                
            }
        }   
    }
}
```